byobu won't cycle through search results
I'm having an inconsistent issue with byobu search for last several months. For some searches, it will only navigate to the first backwards result. I have not determined when this breaks or when it works. Here's a few examples of working searches and broken ones.
700 line buffer (tmux history is 100000)
search for status: 33 results, navigates fine
First result line 0
Second result line -161
Last result line: -584
cycles through all 33 just fine
search for wtf: 3: 4 results, will only navigate to first result
First result line: -468
refuses to navigate forward or backwards through results
search for 'password result': 0 results, will not find anything
First result line: ~ -470

Found the culprit in tmux 3.4. Fixed in master which should be 3.5 when it's released https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/4017
